# How to create type safety for sequelize many to many associations methods, like (setModels, etc.)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have model

**model/Caregiver**

```
import { BuildOptions, DataTypes, Model, Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
export interface CaregiverAttributes {
  caregiver_id: number | string;
  caregiver_notification_preferences?: string;
}
export interface CaregiverModel
  extends Model<CaregiverAttributes>,
    CaregiverAttributes {}

export type CaregiverStatic = typeof Model & {
  new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): CaregiverModel;
};

export function CaregiverFactory(sequelize: Sequelize): CaregiverStatic {
  return <CaregiverStatic>sequelize.define(
    'caregiver',
    {
      caregiver_id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      caregiver_notification_preferences: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true,
      tableName: 'caregiver',
    }
  );
}
```

and associations

```
Caregiver.belongsToMany(Patient, {
  foreignKey: 'caregiver_id',
  targetKey: 'caregiver_id',
  as: 'Patient',
});
```

But when I try to **get** or **set**

```
const patients = await caregiver.getPatients();
```

I have an error: **property getPatients does not exist on type CaregiverModel**

Maybe someone have the same problem?

**Notice**: With // @ts-ignore works fine.

Comment: I do a little investigations and found paper about it (https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
Find this paper https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/ , where it is describe.